# Matplotlib pyplot plot axes not aligned to data values

Tags: python, matplotlib

It seems `pyplot.plot` does not align the x and y axes to their respective data endpoints. There are always padded gaps between the plot axes and boundaries and the actual data plot. How can you force a tighter layout for plots such that the plot axes begin and end at their respective terminal data values?

Here's an example of what I mean, with a simple plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,101)
plt.plot(x)
```

[image: example plot]

As you can see, the plot origin (0,0) and the figure axes origin or intersection (bottom left corner of figure box) are not the same. I want to know how to remove the padding so that the line starting from`x[0]` begins from the bottom left corner of the figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,101)
y = np.arange(len(x))
plt.plot(x)
plt.xlim([x.min(), x.max()])
plt.ylim([y.min(), y.max()])
plt.show()
```